# Adding space and extra digit using String.format

Tags: java

I want my output, which is name, followed by age, to have whitespace with 10 characters between. Furthermore, the age must be shown with 2 digits.

So if I write:

```
System.out.printf(name + " " + String.format("%02d", age);
```

I will get something like this (Assume the input given is "Peter", 9):

```
Peter 09
```

But I want 10 lines of space between the name and age.
The following code will give an error, but it shows a bit what I am thinking

```
System.out.printf(name + String.format("%10s02d", age);
```

I know I can add space by doing:

```
String.format("%s10", someVariable);
```

How can I achieve what I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss the space as argument to the format function

```
System.out.printf(name + String.format("%10s%02d",  " ", 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write something like this :

```
    int numberOfSpaces = 10;
    String result = String.format("%s %"+ numberOfSpaces +"s %d", name," ",age );
    System.out.println(result);`
```